# Node.js with express request.body return undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

So, i've been working on backend for my app. The error is in the request, when posting user data.

```
const db = require('../database/connection')

module.exports = {
    async create(req, resp) {
        console.log(req.body)
    }
}
```

The Terminal return **undefined**, but, I post this

```
{
    "name": "victor",
    "email": "victor",
    "password": "victor",
    "dtnasc": "1999/11/1",
    "sexo": "M",
    "altura": "1,8",
    "peso": "60"
}
```

I try to use Body-parser too, but it's still the same

PS: sorry for the english

Comment: How are you using the function in your ``express`` route?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you don't have the [body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html) middleware set up correctly.

Depending on the version of Express you are using you may have to install it separately.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

If you do have it installed, but still don't find it working make sure to have your express app use the body-parser middleware before you define your routes.

It's a middleware so it will transform the req before passing it along but if you have it after you define your routes  it will never be reached.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
// routes go below
app.get(...)
```

Comment: Just a note: in the latest versions of ``express``, ``bodyParser.urlencoded`` and ``bodyParser.json`` are literately built in to express. [Here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.json), and [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.urlencoded).